# How to create general validation rules for Resources on Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I am familiar with creating validation rules per Resource fields as per the documentation:

```
Text::make('Name')
      ->sortable()
      ->rules('required', 'max:255'),
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to leverage the abstract `Resource` class which is extended by Nova Resources, to create general validation rules which will be used by all Resources that extends this class.

I am trying to achieve because I have various resources with common fields that have common validation rules. I find it a bit redundant to create the attach the same validation rules to my the same Resource Fields over multiple Resources.

**Resource A:**

```
    /**
 * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('Slug')
             ->rules('required', 'slug', 'min:2', 'max:30')
             ->creationRules('unique:slug,name')
             ->updateRules('unique:slug,name,{{resourceId}}'),

        Text::make('Name')
             ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

        HasMany::make('Users'),
        Boolean::make('Status', 'is_active')
    ];
}
```

**Resource B:**

```
**
 * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        Text::make('Slug')->hideFromIndex()
            ->hideFromIndex()
            ->rules('required', 'slug', 'min:2', 'max:30')
            ->creationRules('unique:slug,name')
            ->updateRules('unique:slug,name,{{resourceId}}'),

        Text::make('Label'),
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

        Text::make('Formulae'),

        HasMany::make('Test Template', 'Questionnaires', 'App\Nova\Resources\Questionnaire'),
    ];
}
```

Resource A & B share the same validation rules for field "Slug".

Would be possible to create general rules rather than duplicate them as such?